# Is there a way to get all registered message-converters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to somehow inject all `HttpMessageConverter` instances registered in Spring-MVC. I can successfully inject all that have been registered via.

```
private HttpMessageConverter[] converters;
@Autowired
public void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter[] converters) {
    this.converters = converters;
}
```

However this only injects if the converter was registered inside the context (i.e. if defined outside of `<annotation-driven>`).

I did figure I would try using `<beans:ref` inside the `<annotation-driven><message-converters>` but it is not supported in spring-web 3.1.

Is there some class I can inject that may have a property I could use to get converters? Ideally I'd like to see the order in the filter chain they are registered in too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, the message converters are directly instantiated within the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter registered using the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` xml tag, and the message-converters subtag explicitly expect the bean to be defined inline.

However, a workaround is to define the handler adapter and inject in the converters this way:

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
                    <property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="byteArrayConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jaxbConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="byteArrayConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="jaxbConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>

<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Ah, you have been most excellent. The hinting of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` has told me everything I need to know. I can now `@Autowire` a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instance and call it's `getMessageConverters()` method, this returns an array that seems to be in the order registered. FWIW I did not wish to modify this, I merely wished to report on which converters were registered and in which order.

Comment: One extra bit of information, I was calling getMessageConverters() in my @Autowire constructor. At that time, all message converters had not been registered. What worked for me was calling getMessageConverters() just before I needed to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Spring puts all the converters behind an implementation of `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService` . You need to inject an instance of that interface into your class, you can read more in the spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-ConversionService-API) (including an example of how to inject it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try injecting a bean of type `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` but depending on your configuration, you might not have an instance!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did from Biju's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11970698/140037