# Read only properties for POST in spring data rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

Is there a possibility to make some information read only at spring data rest for jpa entities i.e. these are included in the GET, but cannot be set via POST.

Do I have to do it myself?

Example is:

```
public class Foo{

@Id
private String id;

@ReadOnlyProperty
private int updateCount;

}
```

Now you can set the updateCount via POST.
The field is used internally and also changed internally. It should also be updateable internally. The GET response should include this field, but should not initially be set via POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` works.

```
public class Foo{

    @Id
    private String id;


    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) 
    private int updateCount;
    //getter setter

}
```

Comment: I don't know but I am using Kotlin with Spring Data Rest and it doesn't work, it says that the value is missing in POST request JSON...

Answer (score 1):

@JsonCreator tells `Jackson` to use this constructor to instantiate an object. In this example, `updateCount` is not one of the constructor parameter, so even if the `POST` or `PUT` request JSON body contains an property named `updateCount`, this JSON property `updateCount` in JSON body is ignored. As you can see in the constructor `Foo.updateCount` is initialized by code.

A getter `getUpdateCount` with @JsonProperty make the field `updateCount` serializable, that is be included in the response body to a GET request.

A setter `setUpdateCount` with @JsonIgnore make the field `updateCount` not-deserializable, that is be ignored on a `PATCH` update request.

I suggest you to remove the setter `setUpdateCount`, and use method `incrementUpdateCount` to increment.

```java
public class Foo{

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private int updateCount;

    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {

        this.name = name;
        this.updateCount = 0;
    }

    // getter and setter of name is omitted for briefness

    @JsonProperty
    public int getUpdateCount() {
        return updateCount;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setUpdateCount(int updateCount) {
        this.updateCount = updateCount;
    }

    public void incrementUpdateCount(int change) {
        this.updateCount += change;
    }

    public void incrementUpdateCount() {
        this.updateCount += 1;
    }
}
```

Disable Jackson mapper feature [`INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS), by adding to your `application.properties`

```
spring.jackson.mapper.infer-property-mutators = false
```

or `application.yml` if you use YAML format

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      infer-property-mutators: false
```

If Jackson mapper feature [`INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS) is enabled, a getter implies a field to be deserialzable.
I have a [test case](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-boot-study/commit/72e6f49fa85747559b324416c57bbe6a727eb7f8) to show the difference between enable and disable this feature.

Comment: But I have some properties that are should not set via POST or should be ignored

Comment: @SirWayne Question 1: How your entity is created? Created by HTTP POST request? Created by "new" and then "save"? Or the entity (data) already exists in database?

Comment: @SirWayne Question 2: What action does your POST request take? Create or update?

Comment: It's a new entity via POST. I will add a example pojo

Comment: So i have to mix JPA and Jackson Annotation in own class, right?

Comment: @SirWayne If you don't want Jackson annotation on this class, you can use Jackson Mixin. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192852/configuring-jackson-mixin-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: But the json ignore is not working on the setter the field is set.

Maybe i have to disable the USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS ?

Comment: It seems @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) is working

Comment: Oh yes. @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) should work in your situation. I failed to change my mind from my use case "allow initialization and disallow update" to the truly read-only use case. My mind was fixed and I forgot the access property.

Comment: You can post your solution @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) as an answer to help others, in case they don't see our discussion in the comment.